# Can't open class php in php file with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, class

I want to include a class that has been made ​​to the php file, here I am using **.htaccess**. but once put into a php file, the php class can not be opened or loaded in a php file. The following directory structure in my web.

```
htdocs/
       mysite/
              src/
                     App/
                     Login.php <-- class file php
              public/
                     login.php <-- file php
```

this is login class (**mysite/src/App/Login.php**)

```
class Login {

     private $username;
     //etc...

}
```

this is login file (**mysite/public/login.php**)

```
require('../src/App/Login.php');

$login = new Login();
```

this is .htaccess file (**mysite/.htaccess**)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# skip for existing files/directories (/assets will be skipped here)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# for public directory
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/(.*)
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

and index.php for rule in .htaccess file (**mysite/index.php**)

```
$requested = empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? false : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$server_name = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

switch ($requested) {

    case $server_name:
        include 'public/index.php';
        break;
    case $server_name.'login':
        include 'public/login.php';
        break;
    default:
        include 'public/404.php';
}
```

but when I open **localhost/mysite/login** there is an error

> Warning: require(../src/App/Login.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\public\login.php on
>   line ...
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../src/App/Login.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\public\login.php on line ...

Can you help me?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple rule for including files via a relative path where you have not configured an application level `include_path`; **always** base the relative path from that of the **current** script, eg

```
// public/login.php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../src/App/Login.php';
```

Because you're including `public/login.php` from `index.php`, the *include path* includes the parent directory of `index.php`, ie `mysite`. This applies across any files included.

When `public/login.php` tries to include `../src/App/Login.php` it is actually attempting to open `htdocs/mysite/../src/App/Login.php`.

Another thing you might want to try is configure an application level include path. For example, in `index.php`...

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, [
    __DIR__ . '/src/App',
    get_include_path()
]));
```

Now your `src/App` directory is the first searched when performing an `include` or `require` so you can simply run

```
require_once 'Login.php';
```

#### Update

An even better solution would be to register an autoloader, for example (in `index.php`)

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once sprintf('%s/src/App/%s.php', __DIR__, $class);
});
```

Then you can simple create your class without worrying about including the file...

```
$login = new Login();
```

Comment: oh yes, that's work. I'm really don't know with this, because I usually use just require or include function. thank you very much :)

Comment: @user1878292 I've expanded on my answer